# Android: Daily Reminder

Tags: android

I'm creating an Android app where in the user can set the daily reminder, and at the designated time, the phone's alarm goes off and an activity is launched.

App uses the latest version of the SDK and the emulator. How do I get started with this?

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).